# Draft bug with tags on iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, draft

When using the new draft functionality to write a question on the iOS app, if you cancel and save, then reopen the draft, the tags merge together into one tag.

Before:

> [image]

After tapping cancel -> save draft and then opening the draft again:

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.5.2, shipping this week.

I was saving the tag as "bugdesign" instead of "bug;design".